# How to describe someone who has recently entered a new phase of their life

Tags: single-word-requests

I have the sentence below:

> Looking at the budding teenager mature made me feel old.

Is it right to describe someone who has recently become a teenager as budding?

If not, what word should I replace "budding" with? If possible, I would like an adjective to replace the word "budding".

According to the [Macmillian Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/describing-things-which-are-beginning-and-developing), the alternatives include "new", "emerging", "embryonic", "fledgling", "budding", "incipient", "dynamic", and "progressive".

Are any of the alternatives correct in describing someone who has recently entered a new phase of their life? Besides "fledgling", all alternatives seem awkward and unused; I am unsure, however, whether "fledgling" applies here.

I would prefer not to have a compound phrase in this sentence.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't answer the specific question (just the title, perhaps), but related is to "[turn over a new leaf](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+over+a+new+leaf)", which means to start a fresh chapter in one's life, or leave one's past behind. The text and the title don't ask the same thing.

Comment: I don't think you need 'budding' *and* 'mature'. For example "watching the budding teenager", or "watching the maturing teenager", or "watching the teenager mature". I prefer the last, as it only contains one '-ing'.

Answer (score 1):

If the teenager is *maturing*, I suggest that they are in the later stages of development and are better described as **burgeoning** rather than *budding*, which has the feeling of the beginnings of development.

> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/budding)
>
> budding
>
> You use *budding* to describe a situation that is just beginning.
>
> Our budding romance was over. ...the budding private economy.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/burgeoning)
>
> burgeoning
>
> growing or developing quickly:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maturing)
>
> maturing
>
> to become more developed mentally and emotionally and behave in a responsible way:

Comment: The examples in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/burgeon) definitely show burgeoning means developing from something small and/or young. In contrast "budding", which literally means forming a bud, doesn't seem to fit for someone who's been alive 13 or more years. I think the OP wasn't entirely sure what they want to say, but this seems the best answer based on the information given.

Comment: 'Blossoming' seems the better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Biologically speaking, the word for this is **adolescing**— the verb form of **adolescence.**

*to grow toward maturity* : *pass through adolescence*

*it is a young nation, still adolescing.*

[Merriam Webster]

And according to *Wikipedia*:

> Adolescence (from Latin adolescere 'to mature') is a transitional stage of physical and psychological development that generally occurs during the period from puberty to legal adulthood (age of majority). Adolescence is usually associated with the *teenage years*, but its physical, psychological or cultural expressions may begin earlier and end later.